# Почему не меняется иконка приложения?

Tags: java, android

Делаю как написано в учебнике: res -> New -> Image Asset и т.д. Казалось бы всё просто, но уже всю голову сломал. При этом если качаю чужой исходник с кастомной иконкой, то всё отлично работает. Что не так?!

**Манифест**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidtest.iconchange">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

структура папки res:

-layout

-mipmap-hdpi

-mipmap-mdpi

-mipmap-xhdpi

-mipmap-xxhdpi

-mipmap-xxxhdpi

-values

В папках mipmap содержатся png файлы иконок необходимых размеров (от 48х48 до 192х192).

Comment: Не надо код в виде ссылки на сторонний ресурс. Ссылка протухнет и вопрос потеряет смысл. Приведите код текстом прямо в вопросе. Также покажите структуру папок проекта. Конкретнее - `src/main/res/`

Comment: понял, поправил. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Ну... Вроде бы у вас всё правильно... Попробуйте `InstantRun` в настройках студии отключить. И точно у вас во всех 5 папках нужная иконка есть?

Comment: Проблема действительно была во включенном InstantRun. Никогда бы не додумался. Спасибо огромное, Юрий!

Comment: Пожалуйста) Когда работаешь с продуктами гугла надо быть готовым к разочарованию)

Comment: надо быть готовым к неочевидным костылям)
А ещё сейчас заметил, что у release файла всё равно остается дефолтная иконка. Странное поведение при том, что все ресурсы расположены в src\main\res\ и нету спец папок для разделения ресурсов для debug и release.  В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Про релизную сборку не скажу - вообще идей нет)

Comment: Если папок релизных нет, то иконка может быть еще переопределена в build файле.

Comment: там всё стандартно. Собственно, программа обычный Hello World. Всё дефолтное.

Comment: @Georg, возможно, дело в версии девайса-эмулятора. Теоретически, у вас могут быть дефолтные иконки лежать в папке, из которой они берутся для последних версий андроида и, таким образом, заменяют те, что лежат в `mipmap-Xdpi`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение оказалось очень простым. Необходимо всего лишь отключить **InstantRun**.

File –> Settings –> Build, Execution, Deployment –> Instant Run – убрать галочку Enable Instant Run...